# intellij 12.0.4 - idea.exe traffic blocked by Symantec Endpoint Protect

Tags: intellij-idea

On a periodic basis I get a message from Symantec Endpoint Protect that idea.exe traffic has been blocked. I'm assuming this is some type of message regarding how intellij is being used. Is there a way to turn off the out going messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDEA uses a lot of networking: updates check, Maven dependencies download, IDETalk plug-in, code inspections that can verify external resources, communication between the compiler server process, debugger, internal IPC server, version control servers, task servers, etc.

- **Updates** check can be disabled in `Settings` | `Updates`.
- **IdeTalk** plug-in can be disabled in `Settings` | `Plugins`.
- **Non-existent web resource** inspection is configurable in `Settings` | `Inspections`.
- Anonymous **statistics** reporting is controlled in `Settings` | `Usage Statistics`.

Comment: Thanks CrazyCoder! At the very least, I'm sure that'll cut down on the noise quit a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Add Idea application to Exception: 
http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=HOWTO61213

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately I don't have administrative privileges and am unable to add an exception. I think I need to solve this by configuring intellij to not send out the message.

Comment: hm... So sad... I think you have admin privileges.