# Intellij IDEA 12 Can not compile simple code

Tags: java, compiler-errors, intellij-idea

I'm new to Java, I'm trying to compile the simplest code: **hello world**,

```
package com.ninet.first;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] param) {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

when i run it, it says:

```
COMPILATION COMPLETED WITH 1 ERROR 0 WARNINGS
ERROR: FAILED TO CREATE A SELECTOR
```

no class is created.
i have followed couple video tutorials how to use intellij, did everything as in the 
tutorials, tried to re install IDE many times, no changes!!
Project **SDK** are set, I'm using **1.6**

By the way i have no problems in Eclipse.
I can also compile and run my classes in command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [IDEA-98407](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-98407), does that solve your problem? Quote:

> Then you'll have to turn off Settings | Compiler | Use external build.

Comment: Thanks mthmulders. It seams intellij wanted to have internet connection before do any compiling. My firewall was blocking its connection

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Please [check this Knowledge Base document](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23403071) for the networking related issues.

Also [check my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15653836/104891).

Compiler works in a separate process, hence the requirement for the network connection for the IPC, however it's not normal that your firewall is blocking connections on local interface (127.0.0.1) by default.

Comment: I see it know. I always use my firewall in interactive mode, and i didnt think jetbeans supposed to get internet connection, thats how it could happend.